# Función cadena invetida en C

Tags: c

Buenas, alguien me podría explicar una linea del siguiente programa. El programa imprime la inversa de una cadena, por ejemplo la inversa de Juan seria nauJ.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char * str, char *rts, int len)
{
    int num=len;
    str=str+len-1;
    while (num!=0){
        *rts++=*str--;
        num--;
    }
    *rts='\0';
    printf("La cadena invertida es: %s \n", rts);
}

int main()
{
    char cadena[80]="Juan";
    printf("La cadena es %s: \n", cadena); 
    char aux[80];
    int len=strlen(cadena);
    reverse(cadena, aux, len);
    printf("Cadena invertida es: %s", aux);
}
```

La parte que me confunde es esta linea

```
str=str+len-1;
```

Que es lo que esta haciendo exactamente? conozco el uso de puntero, pero esta linea me confunde, alguien podría explicarme. Gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si str es el puntero a la cadena, entonces:

```
str (el puntero) = str (el puntero) + len (la longitud) - 1
```

o sea esta moviendo el puntero, al ultimo elemento del string.

y despues recorre el string, de atras para adelante, para dar vuelta la cadena.

Comment: oh! ahora entiendo, pero una ultima pregunta, en ese caso str tendría la dirección de memoria de la palabra a invertir? porque si es así, al sumarle la longitud de la cadena me estaría saliendo del contenido cadena?

Comment: por eso hace el -1 ;)

Comment: pero en ese caso str valdría 0 antes de hacer la suma de len y restarle 1?, eso es todo gracias por tu ayuda!!! @gbianchi